# How to use public asmx service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, soap, asmx

we have a public `asmx` service that is accessed by our clients through `SOAP`. Until now, only security is that no one other than our clients know about our webservice :). i want to implement some sort of security mechanism on this service. I have gone through [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/security/article.php/c5479/Build-Secure-Web-Services-With-SOAP-Headers-and-Extensions.htm). it seems to me quite good. Is there any better alternative for securing the `asmx` services? and is passing login credentials with `SOAP` headers a good idea (this is what is written in the article) ? Any suggestions, advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article is a better solution:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/security/article.php/c19403/Web-Services-Security-in-The-NET-Framework.htm

It uses the standard WSS ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security )

Comment: in the end he too is suggesting to use either `SOAP`headers to pass login credentials or use windows auth (which is not choice for me.). I wonder how u feel it different from previous article.

Comment: My post was probably not detailed enough, sorry :-)
I actually wanted to suggest using Windows authentication for a couple of reasons:
- You don't need to worry about encrypting your messages when using NTLM or Kerberos
- Security for all web services is managed in one place (IIS Manager) which makes it easy to add users and privileges.

If Windows auth is not a valid option, you should indeed use SOAP headers.
However, in that case you HAVE TO be sure your webservice is not exposed over HTTP. Always use a SSL connection!